# facebook apps hellowolrd

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i just downloaded the library here
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

the followings is my code:

```
require_once "/facebook-platform/clients/php/trunk/facebook.php";

$appapikey = 'secret';
$appsecret = 'secret';

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();

echo "<p>Hello, <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\" />!</p>";
```

but there is nothing output, what's the problem? thanks

Comment: Have you logged in? I'm pretty sure that you require a cookie of some sorts before Facebook API will return fields.

Comment: http://apps.facebook.com/pehelloworld/ try this, blank page

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get this from?

```
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
```

Obviously you are following an out-dated article that is using the **old** SDK. You can just follow the new SDK [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php) from the link **you** posted:

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '191149314281714',
  'secret' => '73b67bf1c825fa47efae70a46c18906b',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <?php if ($user) { ?>
      Your user profile is
      <pre>
        <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      </pre>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

<strike>Also it seems that you are using the **deprecated** FBML in your code, **don't**</strike> FBML is now deprecated. Use iframes instead!

Comment: where should i download the sdk? can you give me the url

Comment: @hkvega: it's the **same** link you posted in the top of your question!

Comment: @hkvega: the `facebook.php` file is the library, I recommend you download the whole package and browse through the folder structure you have.

Comment: The problem is, a lot of the Facebook Dev Wiki is outdated, try using fbdevwiki.com

Comment: @James: "Wiki"! the only "official" resource you should rely on is the [Facebook Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)!

Comment: @ifaour I always find that the information is wrong/deprecated and the examples tend to no longer work.

Comment: @James: where exactly? in the resource you pointed to or the Facebook docs?

Comment: It may have been updated recently, but a few months back all the information was for a previous version of the API.